# How can I stop the video background when I move to another viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can I stop the video background when I move to another `UIViewController`? 
because when I move to another `UIViewController`, the video and background music continue to be played, and when I go back to the main page two videos overlap. so I would like the video and the music to stop when I move to another `UIViewController`, such as when I move in the `UIViewController` for the sign up

```
import UIKit
import SwiftVideoBackground
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class ViewController: UIViewController {

private let videoBackground = VideoBackground()

@IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var mute_img: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet private var muteSwitch: UISwitch!

@IBAction func `switch`(_ sender: UISwitch) {



    if (sender.isOn == true)
    {
        mute_img.isHidden = false
        videoBackground.isMuted = true
    }
    else
    {
        mute_img.isHidden = true
        videoBackground.isMuted = false
    }

    let shouldMute = sender.isOn
    videoBackground.isMuted = shouldMute
    UserDefaults.standard.set(shouldMute, forKey:"isMuted")
   }


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let shouldMute = userDefaults.bool(forKey: "isMuted")
    videoBackground.play(view: view, videoName: "intro", videoType: 
    "mp4", isMuted: shouldMute, willLoopVideo : true)
    muteSwitch.isOn = shouldMute


    }

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if textField == usernameField {
        passwordField.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else if textField == passwordField {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Comment: How do you go to Next View Controller.?

Comment: with a button. renamed sign up, click above and show the second view controller

Comment: which controller are you using to play a video

Comment: So basically before moving to second View controller, you can stop the Video the push the controller to second VC

Answer (score 0):

Forward navigation :

```
videoBackground.pause()
```

Back navigation :

```
videoBackground.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Documentation](https://github.com/dingwilson/SwiftVideoBackground#controls):

You can simply use the pause()

**When leaving the Controller**

```
videoBackground.pause()
```

When Back to Controller:

```
videoBackground.resume()
```

[image]

Comment: so where do I write it on the code? Could you help me?

Comment: When You go to next View Controller by clicking SignUp Button, before Pushing the controller Use videoBackground.pause(). And when you come to first controller back by popViewController, Simply write videoBackground.resume() in viewwillAppear()

Comment: 'VideoBackground' has no member 'pause'